# cycle2 creating too many pagers

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

i'm using jQuery cycle plugin,
for some reason I can't understand, it creates 4 pagers, altough I have only 2 pictures...

code:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> img.bg" data-cycle-pager="#edible_slider_pagers"  data-cycle-pager-template='<i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i>' data-cycle-prev="#edible_slider_prev" data-cycle-next="#edible_slider_next">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/works/edible1.jpg')?>" alt="" class="bg" />
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/works/edible2.jpg')?>" alt="" class="bg" />
</div>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/arrowright.png')?>" id="edible_slider_prev" class="arrow-right" alt="" />
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/arrowleft.png')?>" id="edible_slider_next" class="arrow-left" alt="" />
        <div class="pagers" id="edible_slider_pagers"></div>
```

Comment: Obviously, if I could tell where the problem is, I wouldn't ask for help here.

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle for us to test: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks for helping, the problem was not related to this code..
by the way, the code is fine..